# Pause Assistive Technology - VoiceOver

Tags: swift, voiceover, uiaccessibility, accessibility

I'm trying to call for a pause to VoiceOver technology:

```
UIAccessibility.post(notification: .pauseAssistiveTechnology, argument: UIAccessibility.AssistiveTechnologyIdentifier.notificationVoiceOver)
```

The error is:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'You must pass the identifier of the assistive technology to pause.  See UIAccessibilityConstants.h for the list of valid values.
```

I see that [notificationVoiceOver](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiaccessibility/assistivetechnologyidentifier/1620184-notificationvoiceover) is [an identifier](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiaccessibility/assistivetechnologyidentifier).

Any suggestions? Do I need to `init` an identifier with a `rawValue`?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm trying to call for a pause to VoiceOver technology.

**You can't**, even if the `pauseAssistiveTechnology` type property seems to be appropriate for this purpose at first sight.

Indeed, **VoiceOver can't be paused** because the system needs to take over when need be... which means during the pause you impose as well and a pause means nothing anymore in this context.

A good candidate for this kind of pause is the Switch Control feature as explained in [this discussion](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiaccessibility/notification/1620192-pauseassistivetechnology) of the Apple documentation.